# Multiple selection from one GridView and display data in another GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I am having problem with `GridView` on row command and stack up the data in another `GridView`:

```
private List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> tempDistSPUI
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["tempDistSPUI"] == null)
        {
            return new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
        }
        else
        {
            return (List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>)ViewState["tempDistSPUI"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["tempDistSPUI"] = value;
    }
}

protected void gvSPU_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

    //Get selected standard packing name
    int rowNo = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    SPUname = this.gvSPU.DataKeys[rowNo].Value.ToString();
    lblSPUname.Text = SPUname;

    //Get the record from view state
    itemList = tempDistSPUI;

    itemList = packBLL.getAllDistSPUItemByDistributionIDnSPUName(distributionID, SPUname);
    gvFinalised.DataSource = itemList;
    gvFinalised.DataBind();

    //Save the last record to view state
    this.tempDistSPUI = itemList;
}
```

Let's say when I first selected a row from `gvSPU`, it returns an `itemList` filled with data and display in `gvFinalised`. What I am trying to do is if I selected another row from `gvSPU`, the previous records in gvFinalised will still there and stack up another `itemList` from the secondly selected row instead of wiping up the record previously and display the latest `itemList` data.

I am using `viewState` but it does not work.

**EDIT**

```
protected void lbnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> prodVariantDetail = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();

        int packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

        // get the last product variant IDs from ViewState
        prodVariantIDList = this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs;

        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            GridView gvProduct = (GridView)ri.FindControl("gvProduct");
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvProduct.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                //Prevent gvFinalised to store duplicate products
                if (cb.Checked && !prodVariantIDList.Any(i => i == gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    // add the corresponding DataKey to idList
                    prodVariantIDList.Add(gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < prodVariantIDList.Count; i++)
        {
            prodVariantDetail.Add(packBLL.getProdVariantDetailByID(prodVariantIDList[i]));
        }

        //Check if itemList and prodVariantDetail list contains any duplicate records
        var Gdupes = itemList.GroupBy(x => new { x.id }).Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any()).ToList();
        List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> dupes = Gdupes.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
        prodVariantDetail = itemList.Except(dupes).ToList();

        gvFinalised.DataSource = prodVariantDetail;
        gvFinalised.DataBind();

        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvFinalised.Rows)
        {
            //Get the product packaging quantity by productName
            string name = gr.Cells[1].Text;
            int productQuantity = packBLL.getProductQuantityByName(name, distributionID);
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.Cells[5].FindControl("tbQuantity");

            if (productQuantity == 0)
            {
                tb.Text = productQuantity.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                tb.Text = (productQuantity / packagesNeeded).ToString();
            }
        }

        // save prodVariantIDList to ViewState
        this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs = prodVariantIDList;
    }

private List<string> SelectedVariantDetailIDs
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"] == null)
            {
                return new List<string>();
            }
            else
            {
                return (List<string>)ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `itemList` is stacked up when `gvSPU_OnRowCommand` is executed? When you do this: `itemList = packBLL.getAllDistSPUItemByDistributionIDnSPUName(distributionID, SPUname);`, `itemList` will be replaced so I don't think it will be stacked up with the previous records.

Comment: Yeah it won't stack up for now. But I have no idea why is it so since I am using viewState for it already.

Comment: My scenario is let's say I got SPU small and SPU medium in gvSPU. First, I select SPU small from gvSPU and the item inside it should be displayed at gvFinalised. After that, I select SPU medium again, so my gvFinalised should be populated by the item inside SPU small and medium. However, for now, it just display the item in SPU medium and wiped up the SPU small

Comment: Is there any way to amend my code so that whenever gvSPU row is selected, it will get the records and store into a list. And after that, transfer all the record into itemList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following lines:

```
//Get the record from view state
itemList = tempDistSPUI; 

// here itemList will be replaced 
itemList = packBLL.getAllDistSPUItemByDistributionIDnSPUName(distributionID, SPUname);
```

First you assign `tempDistSPUI` from ViewState to `itemList`, but then you replace `itemList` at the next line. You need to add the elements returned from `packBLL.getAllDistSPUItemByDistributionIDnSPUName` to `itemList` instead of replacing `itemList`. Here's what I would do using [List.AddRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
itemList = tempDistSPUI; 

// add the returned elements to itemList
itemList.AddRange(packBLL.getAllDistSPUItemByDistributionIDnSPUName(distributionID, SPUname));
```

**UPDATE**
To prevent duplication with the previous elements:

```
itemList = tempDistSPUI; 

List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> itemListNew = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
itemListNew = packBLL.getAllDistSPUItemByDistributionIDnSPUName(distributionID, SPUname);

// get all previous IDs in a List<int>
List<int> previousIDs = itemList.Select(x => x.id).ToList();

// filter itemListNew and add the elements to itemList
itemList.AddRange(itemListNew.Where(x => !previousIDs.Contains(x.id));
```

Comment: It worked. But however, I wanted to prevent duplication of same product before adding them into the tempList. I put in the code in EDIT portion and it turns out to be not function again.

Comment: the add range method cancel out the duplication of ID and display in gridview. However, when I try to insert into database, the duplicate was still there. Any clues?

Comment: How do you insert to database? Do you use all IDs from `tempDistSPUI`?

Comment: I add the itemList into another list and did a very complicated codes.

Comment: If I select gvSPU twice, the itemList displayed at the gvFinalised contains no duplicate. After that, I copy over the itemList and store into another list. At this point, there's duplication somehow. Can you please help me check with the edited portion?

Comment: The edited portion code is not clear, in which method is it exactly? And what's the point of taking values from `SelectedVariantDetailIDs`?

Comment: It's like when I check row from another gridview, I append it to the gvFinalised.

Comment: the itemlist did cancel out duplication and display in gridview. But however, when I try to insert into database, there is duplication. I wonder is it because of the viewState?

Comment: `when I try to insert into database, there is duplication. I wonder is it because of the viewState?`, how would I know that without seeing the code? Which list do you take to database, and is that list duplicated?